# CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED:failure on AMLS Compute after running training for some time

Tags: azure, tensorflow, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm facing a "Error polling for event status: failed to query event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED: unspecified launch failure" while running Tensor flow model training on Azure ML Compute. This error occurs randomly sometimes after running for few epochs.

This appears randomly and works sometimes with re-run on the same ML compute and sometimes by re-creating new ML compute.

Found a suggestion on why it's happening here :
https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/gpu-occasionally-gets-lost-when-running-tensorflow/69620

Could you please help in understanding the actual root cause for it.

Error Message:

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_event.cc:48] Error polling for event status: failed to query event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED: unspecified launch 
F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:194] Check failed: status == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (7 vs. 0)Failed to set cuDNN stream.
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1000] could not wait stream on event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED: unspecified launch failure
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_event.cc:48] Error polling for event status: failed to query event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED: unspecified launch 
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_event.cc:48] Error polling for event status: failed to query event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED: unspecified launch 
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1000] could not wait stream on event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED: unspecified launch failure
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1000] could not wait stream on event: CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED: unspecified launch failure
```

Placed the version detail below:

1. ML Compute Type : Intel(R) MPI Library for Linux* OS, Version 2018 Update 3 Build 20180411 (id: 18329)
2. tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1
3. Multi-GPU - NC24

Comment: Is your issue resolved now ? Else, it seems like driver mismatch, for more details please refer [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33536) may help you.